# How do I deploy a ssr Astro site with a Node.js adapter on Netlify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering, netlify, astrojs

How do I deploy a server-side rendered Astro site with a Node.js adapter on Netlify?

When i push this site to production I see:

> Runtime.ImportModuleError - Error: Cannot find module 'sharp' Require stack: - /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/entry.js - /var/task/entry.js - /var/runtime/index.mjs

this is probably becouse I showes me in functions tab that i have entry function but i dont specyfy it.

this is my astro.config.mjs

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import preact from "@astrojs/preact";
import sitemap from "@astrojs/sitemap";
import image from "@astrojs/image";
import compress from "astro-compress";

// https://astro.build/config
import node from "@astrojs/node";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  site: "https://kluzko.tech",
  trailingSlash: "always",
  output: "server",
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone",
  }),
  integrations: [
    preact({
      compat: true,
    }),
    sitemap({
      customPages: ["https://kluzko.tech/about", "https://kluzko.tech/contact"],
    }),
    image({
      serviceEntryPoint: "@astrojs/image/sharp",
    }),
    compress({
      css: true,
      html: false,
      img: true,
      js: true,
      svg: false,
      logger: 1,
    }),
  ],
  vite: {
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ["react-hot-toast"],
    },
  },
});
```

and here is my netlify.toml

```
[build]
  command = "pnpm build"
  publish = "dist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install `npm i sharp` as you've instructed Astro to import it (`serviceEntryPoint: "@astrojs/image/sharp"`).

Here is how you could find it out yourself and learn something new from Astro source code.

[Github search in Astro repo for keyword `sharp`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Awithastro%2Fastro+sharp&type=code) brought me to [this piece of code](https://github.com/withastro/astro/blob/dec072f57fb7ae73bb94b14ea329c9c5aeba5921/packages/integrations/image/src/index.ts#L95):

```
import(resolvedOptions.serviceEntryPoint === '@astrojs/image/sharp'
                    ? './loaders/sharp.js'
                    : './loaders/squoosh.js');
```

Knowing that you've specified '@astrojs/image/sharp' for `serviceEntryPoint` in your `astro.config.mjs`, let's open [./loaders/sharp.ts](https://github.com/withastro/astro/blob/dec072f57fb7ae73bb94b14ea329c9c5aeba5921/packages/integrations/image/src/loaders/sharp.ts#L1) and first line reveals the import that throws an error as `sharp` package is not installed in your project:

```
import sharp from 'sharp';
```

Hope that helps!